# Angular 1.3: How to return response asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My service calls a REST endpoint, but the response is never returned, the app shows always "...".

The service:

```
myServices.factory('myService', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return {version:   
        function getVersion() {
                var data="...";
                var restCall = $resource('http://localhost/api/version', {}, {method:"GET", params: {}, isArray: true}).query();
                restCall.$promise.then(function(response){data=response;});
                return data;                
            }
        }
  }]);
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.version = myService.version();
```

I know I could state `return $resource([...]);`, but I would like to alter the response in the service itself before returning it to the controller. How could I do that?

Comment: can't you use the transformResponse attribute of the resource? http://jsfiddle.net/roadprophet/prtAP/

Comment: Because your scope is bound to a string value, after callback even if you update `data` scope value remains same. Use object or return promise.

Comment: @Chandermani: How would I do that (using object)?

Comment: How does the response look like is it a string?